# How to query random objects in realm react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

Suppose I have a collection of 50 users, how to randomly select 10 users in realm react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you assign each user an id in Realm (an integer would be fine). You then use a random number generator to select a number between 1-50, and select that user from Realm - loop until 10 are selected. You should keep the selected users in a list, and retry in case the random user was already picked.

Comment: Thanks, I did it like this let randomUser =  user[random_number], where user = realm.objects('users')